# What's wrong with this SELECt Query?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim SQLData As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Name =" + TextBox1.Text + " And Last = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'", SQLData)
        SQLData.Open()
        If cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar > 0 Then
            Label1.Text = "Record Found ! " & TextBox1.Text & " " & TextBox2.Text
            Return
        End If

        Label1.Text = "Record Not Found ! "
        SQLData.Close()
    End Sub
```

I write this code to find whether the record entered in textbox1 and textbox2 exists or not ..if record exist ..then in label1 the text would be RECORD FOUND else NO RECORD FOUND

ERROR :

****when i enter in textbox1 and textbox2 then on button click event it shows the error :** ***Invalid column name ,,*****

Comment: SQL-Injection Hurray! Ironically, that's exactly your problem.

Comment: I think the problem is that there is a column name which is invalid. Either Name or Last isn't a field in the table. Also I think you need to read up on sql injection. Your code it's very secure.

Comment: You should also set `Option Strict ON` as VB.Net default in Visual Studio. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Please use [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) collection. Please!! For the sake of better programming.

```
Dim cmdSelect As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Name = @Name And Last = @Last", SQLData)

cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",TextBox1.Text)
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last",TextBox2.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox1.Text` should be passed inside single quotes (`'`).

Beside that, it seems to be another [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'` around the Textbox1.text value

e.g

`'" + TextBox1.Text + "'`

Answer (score 0):

You should really not doing it like this since this is open for sql injection. Except from that I think you are missing some `'` in the query around `TextBox1.Text`.